# $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$ where $F$ is splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $f = x^{3} + x^{2} + 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, rational-numbers

I need to find $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$ where $F$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $f = x^{3} + x^{2} + 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, I know from looking at its derivative that $f$ has only one real root. Moreover, from the rational roots theorem, I know that $f$ has no rational roots. Therefore, $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$. Is $[F:\mathbb{Q}] = 3$, then? Do I need to find out what $F$ actually is here? And in order to do that, do I need to find what the actual roots are?

Thanks.

Comment: Take real root $\alpha$ of $f$. Then $\mathbb Q[\alpha] = 3$ since $f$ is its minimal polynomial. But, $\mathbb Q[\alpha]\subseteq\mathbb R$ so it doesn't contain complex roots of $f$, and therefore cannot be splitting field of $f$. Therefore, you'd need to adjoin at least one more root to $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ to get the splitting field, so $[F:\mathbb Q]>3$.

Comment: In your case, you have $[F:Q]\leq 3!$. Since you do not have complex root, $[F:Q]=6$.

Comment: @Ennar - What do you mean by $\mathbb Q[\alpha]=3$?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard, oh, what a typo. I meant the degree, i.e. $[\mathbb Q[\alpha]:\mathbb Q] = 3$. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need is $[F:\Bbb{Q}]$, you have everything required to compute it.  You've determined that $f$ is irreducible, so let $\alpha$ be a root.  Then $[\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]:\Bbb{Q}]=3$ and since all roots are not real, $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]$ cannot be the splitting field.  The minimum polynomial for the other two roots of $f$ is a quadratic with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]$, in fact $f/(x-\alpha)$.  By multiplicativity of degrees the splitting field must have degree $3\cdot 2=6$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: it's not irreducible - it has one real root.

Comment: @ALannister Having a real root means the polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb{R}$.  Since it has no rational root, it is *irreducible* over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: okay, I misread when you said "since all roots are not real". I took that to mean "no root is real" and was like "what's he on about?" rather than "there exists roots that are not real" as was intended.